# contentEditable + selectAll: Firefox won't allow keyboard input on dynamically generated content

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, contenteditable, selectall

I'm having a problem in Firefox (other browsers seem to work fine) with dynamically generated elements containing a `contenteditable="true"` attribute:

If I `selectAll` (either dynamically, or with my mouse), Firefox won't allow keyboard input.

Please see my [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/6sTJh/2/) for reference. This appears to only affect Firefox.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.edit').live('dblclick', function () {
    document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null);
});

$('#live').append('<p class="edit" contenteditable="true">This content is generated. Firefox will not allow keyboard input when "ALL" is selected.</p>');
});
```

**EDIT:**
Here is the actual app I'm working on (pardon the dust): [cr8.me/app/ff.html](http://cr8.me/app/ff.html) - What I'm wanting is to click (double-click to select all text) a Note, Category, or Plan Title to edit it. Does it work for anyone? Maybe it's just my configuration - or poor scripting. Lines 137, 572 are relevant.

Comment: Works fine for me in Firefox 3.6. Which version do you use? 6.0?

Comment: Huh, provide even more details then (OS) :) I've checked in Fx 3.6.22 (Win XP) and 6.0.2 (Win 7 on virtual machine) and both work correctly.

Comment: 6.0.2 on Mac OS 10.7.1 - but now I'm noticing it's working intermittently in my example - but not in my app.

Comment: Here is the actual app I'm working on (pardon the dust): http://cr8.me/app/ff.html - What I'm wanting is to click (double-click to select all text) a Note, Category, or Plan Title to edit it. Does it work for anyone? Maybe it's just my configuration - or poor scripting. Lines 137, 572 are relevant.

Comment: Ha, the app doesn't work (Fx 3.6 / XP), though the fiddle still does.

Comment: Yep, I can confirm that too - Firefox 3.6.2 and 6.0 / Linux Ubuntu - fiddle works while your app is not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently Firefox has issues with contenteditable on *span* elements (I'm assuming that's the case with other *display: inline* elements, though I've not tested it).
Problem can be solved with simply **replacing spans with divs**. What's more - that divs can have "display: inline" property set on them using css and still working fine.

Check the working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/6sTJh/5/. 
The button with label "Add buggy" dynamically adds a span with contenteditable and its not working as expected, while button "Add working" appends div with contenteditable attribute and it's working just fine.

So is your app - when I replaced all the contenteditable spans with divs, the editing is working just fine in firefox 3.6 and firefox 6.0.

*Side note:*
As to your application code - don't use the same *id* on multiple nodes (like you're doing with the same id "note-title" on every note) or you can get unexpected behavior from various browsers.

Generale rule is that you can have only one element with a given id on one page. Use *class* to "group" more than one elements and select them later on.

Comment: +1, good answer. I had trouble with contentEditable before, this was similar to my issue.